# BrightCove API - how to get the record in descending order by using video id

Tags: php, brightcove

I am using BrightCove API with PHP. Need help for API response.

If I have first passed the id "5" then it should return the video record of id "5" id but it is returning the first data of "2" video id.

is there any way to get the data in passed id parameters?

```
 GET /v1/accounts/MyAccountID/videos?q=id:5+id:2
 HTTP/1.1
 Host: cms.api.brightcove.com
```

**Current response:**

```
   [
   {
    "id": "2",
    "account_id": "4545",
   }

   {
    "id": "5",
    "account_id": "12121",
   }
 ]
```

**I want response like below:**

```
 [
 {
    "id": "5",
    "account_id": "12121",
 }
 {
    "id": "2",
    "account_id": "4545",
 }
```

]

Please help.

Comment: Just sort the response.

Comment: thanks sir for reply, my number of IDs is very big. is there any way to get the records by passed ids sequence like below?

https://cms.api.brightcove.com/v1/accounts/AccountID/videos?q=id:2178817996001+id:5489114665001+id:5517007326001+id:5516879800001+id:5516657758001+id:5516901906001+id:5516678509001+id:5516359096001+id:5516212303001+id:5516359018001+id:5515740342001+id:5515702916001+id:5516240039001+id:3950909953001+id:5515609251001+id:5515260786001+id:2436974012001+&limit=100

Comment: I'm guessing the fact that you have different `account_id`s is contrived and unrealistic? The request you're making is a search so the semantics around ordering is very different (i.e. you're not actually requesting a list of videos you're specifying a list of search clauses that happen to match an identifier attribute). You  should try something like `/v1/accounts/MyAccountID/videos/5,2` instead which at a glance appears to be supported (and should yield slightly better performance).

Comment: Sorting the response after retrieval should also be perfectly reasonable: if the result size is large enough that sorting becomes costly the requests should likely be batched (for other reasons also) and the fact that a comparison sort isn't needed should also allow avoidance of naive sorting costs.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is working if videos are 10 or less than 10 . If we have more than 10 videos then it is giving the below Error

[
    {
        "error_code": "ILLEGAL_PATH",
        "message": "A request for more than 10 videos is not supported"
    }
]

Comment: Yes, there is currently a limit of 10 for those requests, but any greater number can be handled with batching/concurrent requests. That limit seems potentially low on the Brightcove side (especially if the search effectively bypasses it) so raising it may be considered but that doesn't help you immediately: opening a support ticket could help track that possibility.

Comment: Some form of batching should be considered for a larger number of videos should be considered in any case to help avoid and handle any possible issues while transferring.